# getting a city suggestions using google angular

Tags: angular

Can I get city suggestions from google maps after user entered the name so user can choose the correct one?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL51N.png)

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead

Comment: i have a form (name, email ,city, ...) , I did not manage to display the list of possible cities in the input area (by accessing google). can you help me please @AdritaSharma

Comment: You need to show what you have tried

Comment: for exemple when I write the letter 'n', all the cities that start with this letter are displayed (powered by google) @AdritaSharma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There is an Angular Material component to get this behavior. Try to use the 
[Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component. There you can filter the inputs.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/xxmkkyxgqva?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts